# Django model save() method not called when using Model.objects.create()

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a primary key ID CharField in my model `Image`, I want to create unique IDs for newly created objects. I try to achieve this by overriding the model's save method:

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk: # is created
            self.id = uuid.uuid4().hex
            while Image.objects.filter(id=self.id).exists():
                self.id = uuid.uuid4().hex
        return super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

The problem is, `save()` doesn't seem to be called when I create objects with `Image.objects.create()`, it is only called when I create the object with `image=Image(...)` and then call `image.save()`. As a result, the newly created object has no id assigned unless specified, which causes PostgreSQL to throw a `non_unique primary key` error.

How can I make sure that unique IDs are created upon calling `Image.objects.create()`?

Django version: 1.11.3

UPDATE: I realized that the overridden save() method was not called either. Turns out the problem was I was calling model's `save` method in a migration. As it is pointed out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37685925/463463) custom model methods are not available in migrations. I will have to copy the model's save method to the migration file.

Comment: The point of UUID (universally unique identifier) is that you can always assume that two UUIDs are distinct. You'd be better off setting your `id` field to have `default=uuid.uuid4` (no parentheses after the `uuid4`) and this will happen automatically on object creation.

Comment: I wish :( Database was designed before me and now it is very difficult to change the primary key field without losing data so this is not an option for me.

Comment: by the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects) `To create an object, instantiate it using keyword arguments to the model class, then call save() to save it to the database.` so please clarify why you think so?

Comment: is you model `pk` name `id`?

Comment: docs also say that `To create and save an object in a single step, use the create() method.` so I would expect this using `create()` cause a problem. Besides, code base is big and there are different ways that create objects (e.g. `get_or_create()`). I don't want to go through the whole code base and hunt down these methods to see whether they use `create()` or `save()`.

Comment: yes, model `pk` name is `id`

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done in general. In between your if statement checking that the ID doesn't exist yet and you setting it, something else could add a new row with that ID. Which is why other solutions are used -- an auto-incrementing ID that the database ensures is unique, or a UUID that has a really tiny chance of being unique.

Luckily, you use one those. With UUIDs the custom is to just *assume* that they are unique.

The way to do it is to set a function returning the unique ID as the field's default:

```
def uuid_hex():
    return uuid.uuid4().hex

class YourModel(models.Model):
    id = CharField(unique=True, primary_key=True, default=uuid_hex, null=False)
```

Comment: Forgot that the default has to be an actual function, not a lambda. Does this work?

Comment: I think it does. The problem was that I was trying to do this in a migration (see my update).

Comment: @yam: ah yes, in a migration you don't get the real model classes, you get something model-like that has the same fields as the models had at the time the migrations were made.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the real `save` method while overriding the model `save` method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk: # is created
        self.id = uuid.uuid4().hex
        while Image.objects.filter(id=self.id).exists():
            self.id = uuid.uuid4().hex
    super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Check docs:
[Overriding predefined model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

Also it's not a good idea to override the default `id`. If you need another unique field to be used as something like an ID then i recommend adding another field alongside the default `id` field.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd forgotten to add that part. I do call the save method. Updating my post.

Comment: Oh, okay then, but still i don't think this is a good idea. Assigning id in django level is not a good idea. let the main id be created by database which is what it does best and add another field.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately the database was designed this way by someone else and it turns out to be very difficult (if not impossible) to change the ID field into a self-incrementing integer field without breaking M2M relationships with Django migrations. So this is the only other solution I could think of.

Comment: I see. I would've tried to convert the data to a new structure that fits better with both django and new technologies if the amount of data isn't huge but still i don't have enough information to actually recommend that. So best of lucks ;)